# Unable to integrate Stripe checkout into Vue JS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to redirect to stripe checkout using a click event that calls the payStripe function

```
<button @click="payStripe" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Place Order</button>
```

I have imported stripe into my Vue component like so;

```
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
const stripe = loadStripe('MY-KEY');
```

I am using Firebase cloud functions and axois to fetch the session and store this to a data property, this works fine.

But, the payStripe method, when called, gives the following error;

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: stripe.redirectToCheckout is not a function"
```

Here is the function i am using which, from all accounts is similar to the Stripe API docs;

```
  data() {
    return {
      sessionId: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    //This function sends us to the stripe checkout
     payStripe() {
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
          sessionId: this.sessionId
        })
        .then(function(result) {
          console.log(result);
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
     }
  },
```

I had original issues with babel-core, so i updated to @babel/core to get rid of rest operator issues when compling code, but faced with this new issue. Any advice would be great. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Phil when adding await to loadStripe, my vue app gives the error 'The keyword await is reserved'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/stripe-js#loadstripe), `loadStripe` returns a promise that you must wait to resolve.

Try something like

```js
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js"
const stripeInit = loadStripe('MY-KEY') // returns a promise
```

and when you want to use stripe

```js
methods: {
  //This function sends us to the stripe checkout
  payStripe() {
    // wait for the promise to resolve first
    stripeInit.then(stripe => {
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: this.sessionId
      }).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Laravel Homestead as a vm, I turned `ssl: true` in Homestead.yaml, and entered `https://site.test` manually in the URL. I didn't get a valid https certificate, but the vue-stripe components load and it works